# mod_rewrite subdomain in Symfony2

Tags: mod-rewrite, symfony, url-rewriting, subdomain

Please help with mod_rewrite subdomain to some Symfony2 routing. It is like 3 months now I spent time to solve this with my Symfony2 project but after reading tons of apache mod_rewrite and mod_alias documentation and trying hundreds of examples... it still doesn't work!

What I try to solve is, when user enter address of some specific subdomain:
**XXXXXXX.example.com**

He sees content that is actually under
**www.domain.com/tag/XXXXXXX/**

but he is not redirected or URL isn't changed -- it should just stay XXXXXX.example.com as he enters.

I need to resolve this with Apache VirtualHost and sites-enabled file (not with SubdomainListener) but the most I can solve on my own with mod_rewrite is having

**XXXXXXX.example.com**

Rewriting (transparently) itself to

**XXXXXXXX.example.com/tag/XXXXXXXX**  or
**XXXXXXXX.example.com/app.php/tag/XXXXXXXX/**

which of course is not what I try to achieve. I try to achieve internal (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html) redirection so user don't see that.  Any help with working soultions would be otherworldly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3378) commit, you can use subdomains in Symfony natively, but unfortunately it's a Symfony 2.2 feature. If you need subdomains, this still is the best way to do this, however.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. Maybe someday I could use it with Symfony 2.2. I wonder if there is Apache VirtualHost solution for that. I really need it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I've tried to do that too unsuccessfully :( Symfony 2.2 is in beta phase though, I think it's pretty safe to use it.